# NSLayoutConstraint and dynamic width and height

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I have this code:

```
[parent.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(0)-[myView]-(0)-|"
                        options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                        metrics:nil
                          views:@{ @"myView":myView }]];
```

May I understand it wrong, I don't know. I want the `myView` get all over the `parent.view` area. But I just got an error:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14d645d0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x14d32ce0]   (Names: '|':UILayoutContainerView:0x14dbd6a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14d64600 H:[UIView:0x14d32ce0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UILayoutContainerView:0x14dbd6a0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x16184340 h=-&- v=-&-UIView:0x14d32ce0.midX == UILayoutContainerView:0x14dbd6a0.midX + 140>"
)
```

I tried `@"[myView]-(0)-|"`, but I got error too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set `myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO`